# awk: print each column of a file into separate files

Tags: awk

I have a file with 100 columns of data. I want to print the first column and i-th column in 99 separate files, I am trying to use

```
for i in {2..99}; do awk '{print $1" " $i }' input.txt > data${i}; done
```

But I am getting errors

```
awk: illegal field $(), name "i"
 input record number 1, file input.txt
 source line number 1
```

How to correctly use $i inside the {print }?

Comment: You need not to have a `for` loop and `awk` inside it. `awk` could read the Input_file with having `for` or `while` loop in itself too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do what you try to accomplish :

```
for i in {2..99}; do
    awk -v x=$i '{print $1" " $x }' input.txt > data${i}
done
```

Note

- the `-v` switch of awk to pass variables
- `$x` is the nth column defined in your variable `x`

Note2 : this is not the fastest solution, one [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) call is fastest, but I just try to correct your logic. Ideally, take time to understand `awk`, it's never a wasted time

Comment: @glenn jackman, what's the point of editing ? Doesn't work now (no output) consider: `awk -v x=yah 'BEGIN{print $x}'` VS `awk -v x=yah 'BEGIN{print x}'`

Comment: That would be an order of magnitude slower than just doing it in 1 call to awk. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice

Comment: I started with OP try, I just correct it. I agree it's slower than 1 awk call, but for a one shot command it can be sufficient. And like James Brown said (not this one, the other guy), there's a gap understanding a simple bash+awk than complicated awk

Comment: The OP doesn't know awk or shell and so had a bad idea on how to solve a problem using both but couldn't figure out the syntax so we have 2 choices: 1) show them valid syntax to implement that bad idea, or 2) show them the right way to do it. IMHO we should avoid choice "1". I'm not seeing how the one awk command to do this is any more complicated than the bash+awk command.

Comment: @GillesQuenot, Because the OP wants to see the column **values** in the output files, not just the column **number**. If you use `print $1, x`, you'll get the same static value of `x` for each line of the file. If you use `print $1, $x`, then you'll get the actual values of column `x`.

Comment: Wow, great ! Understand now, it's a very nice idea

Answer (score 2):

An all awk solution. First test data:

```
$ cat foo
11 12 13
21 22 23
```

Then the awk:

```
$ awk '{for(i=2;i<=NF;i++) print $1,$i > ("data" i)}' foo
```

and results:

```
$ ls data*
data2  data3
$ cat data2
11 12
21 22
```

The `for` iterates from 2 to the last field. If there are more fields that you desire to process, change the `NF` to the number you'd like. If, for some reason, a hundred open files would be a problem in your system, you'd need to put the `print` into a block and add a `close` call:

```
$ awk '{for(i=2;i<=NF;i++){f=("data" i); print $1,$i >> f; close(f)}}' foo
```

Comment: here `>>` is not needed, `>` is used for append too.

Comment: @karakfa agreed on the first one but `>>` **is** needed for the 2nd script where he's closing the file after every write

Answer (score 2):

Following single `awk` may help you too here:

```
awk -v start=2 -v end=99 '{for(i=start;i<=end;i++){print $1,$i > "file"i;close("file"i)}}' Input_file
```

Comment: I think you better understand OP needs :)

Comment: @GillesQuenot, you are too good sir, we could give OP suggestions rest is up to OP to accept it, you tried to improvise OP's suggestion(nothing wrong in it) sir I believe and I and James sir tried to give our owns to help OP, cheers :)

Comment: It is mentally a huge leap from bash to all awk--and there is no safety net, only the internet. :D